# Dagger 2 inject() contains a dependency cycle

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have the following setup in Dagger that I'm trying to migrate to Dagger 2:

```
public class Origin {
    final A a;
    public Origin(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

public class A {
    final B b;
    @Inject public A (B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

public class B {
    final Lazy<A> a;
    @Inject public B (Lazy<A> a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Then on my module I have:

```
@Provides @Singleton Origin providesOrigin(A a) {
    return new Origin(a);
}
```

Problem is, even though I'm using `Lazy`, Dagger 2 gives me the following compile time error:

> error: AppComponent.inject() contains a dependency cycle

Am I missing something? I tried replacing `Lazy` with `Provider` but the result is the same.

Comment: I think this will work if you move lazy from B to A.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't help. :(

Comment: How would you create instance with a "new"-statement? You'll have the same cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was that I was using version 2.0 of Dagger where this was still an open [issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/200). Once I updated it to the current 2.1 version the problem was not present anymore.